# GWT Editable Grid : How to revert back changes from field updater?

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I have implemented a a Editable grid and I have used a field updater to update the Model value. Saving to the database is not a problem as I can directly save the entire model to the database. The problem is on clicking cancel or escape, I want to revert back to old value, but I am not able to achieve the same. Any ideas how to go about it?

**Note:**   *Whenever changes are done I am updating the model*

1) I don't want to make an another Async call on clicking cancel.

2) I really want to avoid cloning and store mechanism.

I am currently using GWT 2.4.0

```
column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Abc, String>() {
  @Override
  public void update(Abc object, String value) {
    object.set(value);
    table.redraw();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. When the user changed the value, an asyncCallback sent to the server. If success update the data provider, if fail, update the data provider with the old value.
It seemed pretty easy...but...the table did not get updated with the old value. Moreover, even if it was a success, the textbox kept the correct value, but not formatted as expected from the server (it was a double and I expected to see decimals). So it was again incorrect.

It seems that the editable cell did not get updated from the AsyncDataProvider.

The solution is very simple.
Just call **clearViewData on every update of the FieldUpdater**!!! This way, we make sure that the cell shows the data from the dataprovider and NOT what the user entered. The entry data is safely stored in the dataprovider.

Hope it helps.

```
column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<SQLRow, String>() {
    @Override
    public void update(int index, SQLRow sqlRow, String value) {
        updaterCaller.call(index, fi, sqlRow, value);//Your async method...do mind my params
        ((EditTextCell)columnFinal.getCell()).clearViewData(sqlTable.getKeyProvider().getKey(sqlRow));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Cell Sample in the Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler), it queues changes and allows you to "commit" them to the underlying model afterwards. Cancelling the changes would be a matter of clearing the queue **and** calling [`clearViewData`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractEditableCell.html#clearViewData%28java.lang.Object%29) on each cell for each edited item to make it forget the edited value.

Comment: I looked through that example. They are using ContactInfo as default bean and changing its value on commit. But I am setting the model value on each field update and further I am dealing with genrics, 

    Mygrid <T extends someModel> extends composite

In this case we can't decide which model to use and revert back the changes

Answer (score 0):

You need a key provider and the call `clearViewData` as Thomas suggests.
I read somewhere that if you don't have a key provider you can use the value as the key, but that didn't work for me.

```
  private static final int MAX_AGE = 150;

  private static class Contact {
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public int age;
  }

  private static final ProvidesKey<Contact> KEY_PROVIDER = new ProvidesKey<Contact>() {
    @Override
    public Object getKey(Contact row) {
      return row.name; // assuming names are unique
    }
  };

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    table = new CellTable<Contact>(KEY_PROVIDER);
    ....

    final TextInputCell ageCell = new TextInputCell();
    Column<Contact, String> ageColumn = new Column<Contact, String>(ageCell) {
      @Override
      public String getValue(Contact row) {
        return String.valueOf(row.age);
      }
    };
    ageColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Contact, String>() {
      @Override
      public void update(int index, Contact row, String value) {
        try {
          int intVal = Integer.parseInt(value.trim());
          if (intVal < 0 || intVal > MAX_AGE) {
            throw new NumberFormatException();
          }
          row.age = intVal;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          ageCell.clearViewData(KEY_PROVIDER.getKey(row));
        }
        table.redraw();
      }
    });

    ...
    table.addColumn(ageColumn, "Age");
  }
```